# How to assign value and scope to two concatenated string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML Code:-

```
<ul class="sub-menu collapse">
     <li ng-hide="abcMenuHide" ng-click="showModal('abcMaster')">
        <a>Add/update listOne</a></li>
     <li ng-hide="xyzMenuHide" ng-click="showModal('xyzMaster')">
        <a>Add/Update listTwo</a></li>
</ul> ... and so on
```

I am trying to hide the `<li>` elements on the basis of values assigned to `ng-hide`.
I am making this value in directive like this:-

```
$scope.menuListHide = function(){
        for (var group in $scope.data) {
            if (group != "sectionOne") {
                for (var list in $scope.data[group]) { 
                    for (var key in $scope.data[group][list]) { 
                        if ($scope.data[group][list].view != undefined) {
                            if (!$scope.data[group][list].view) {
                                $scope.(list+"MenuHide") = true; \\This assignment is wrong also I am not able to attach scope to it.
                            }
                        }
                        else if($scope.data[group][list][key].view != undefined){
                            if (!$scope.data[group][list][key].view) {
                                $scope.(key+"MenuHide") = true; \\This assignment is wrong also I am not able to attach scope to it.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }

$scope.menuListHide();
```

Is there any way I can assign `$scope` as well as value to the concatenated string?

Comment: try `$scope[key+"MenuHide"]` syntax instead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this (incorrect syntax):

```
$scope.(list+"MenuHide") = true;
```

you need to do this:

```
$scope[list + "MenuHide"] = true;
```

To change the property dynamically inside an object, you need to wrap the property name with `[]` and call it directly on the object. Since `$scope` is a JavaScript object here, the property `list + "MenuHide"` will be assigned to `true` in `$scope`.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be computed and used as the property name.

Change `$scope.(list+"MenuHide") = true;`

To

```
list = list + "MenuHide";
$scope[list] = true;
```

**OR:** In single line `$scope[list+ "MenuHide"] = true;`